# What are some good libraries for 3D interpolation?

Tags: c++, matlab, 3d, interpolation

What are some good libraries for doing (fast) 3D interpolation? Preferably in C++, but I'm intrested in others, too. (Especially Matlab)

Answer (score 3):

In Matlab, 3D interpolation is performed by [INTERP3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/interp3.html). For some speed gain, pass your method argument preceded by a star (e.g. `'*cubic'` instead of `'cubic'`). For some more speed gain, you can just lift the interpolation code out of the function and skip all the error checking.

A good C++ implementation is likely to be faster, such as the one presented [here on the Matlab File exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21702-3d-volume-interpolation-with-bainterp3-fast-interp3-replacement) (never tested it).